# jQuery parents/children in nested lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In jQuery, parents() and children() are not behaving like I expect with nested lists.  An example:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1
        <ul>
            <li>item a</li>
            <li>item b
                <ul>
                    <li>item i</li>
                </ul>
            </li>          
            <li>item c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

and the javascript:

```
$( 'li' ).click(function(event) {
    $( 'ul' ).not( $(this).parents() ).hide();
    $( this ).children().show();
});
```

If I click "item b" then 'item i' hides.  It seems that "item i" is a child of "item b" and should be shown by $(this).children().show()

Do I have a syntax problem, or am I misinterpreting children/parents in the DOM?

See https://jsfiddle.net/8o71yfpf/ for a working example.

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Children of hidden items cannot be visible. If the children were visible what would it even mean to hide item b?

Comment: what are you wanting to do with item i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `event.stopPropagation();`

when you click on inner li you are also clicking on parent li.

updated https://jsfiddle.net/8o71yfpf/2/

it may help to understand DOM traversal http://www.richfinelli.com/understanding-dom-traversal-in-jquery/